# interface allow any subclass argument

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

If I have classes like these

```
class SuperType {}

class SubTypeOne extends SuperType {}

class SubTypeTwo extends SuperType {}
```

I want to make an interface like this

```
interface TypeHandler {
  public void handle(SuperType arg);
}
```

But allow these to be valid implementation

```
class SubTypeOneHandler implements TypeHandler {
  public void handle(SubTypeOne arg) { }
}
```

As you can see, using a subclass of the argument type defined in the interface.

I tried to re-write the interface using

```
interface TypeHandler {
  public void handle(? extends SuperType arg);
}
```

But it doesn't look like that's valid java.

Comment: You need to make the interface generic.

Comment: @SLaks oh I see, `interface TypeHandler<T extends SuperType>` ? Is that the only way?

Answer (score 3):

That is fundamentally unsafe; if the interface is declared as accepting a `SuperType`, you must be able to call any implementation with any subclass of `SuperType`.

What you actually want is a different, type-safe, version of the interface for each subtype.
That's what generics are for; you need to make the interface generic.